# Select values among duplicates, that dont' have maximum value in one columns(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have rows:

```
123123  2019-07-23 22:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00
123123  2019-07-23 22:00:00 2019-07-04 00:00:00
123123  2019-07-23 22:00:00 2019-07-05 00:00:00
123123  2019-07-25 04:05:06 9999-12-31 00:00:00
123123  2019-07-25 04:05:06 2019-07-04 00:00:00
123123  2019-07-25 04:05:06 2019-07-05 00:00:00
```

You can observe, that there are duplicates in first two columns(first three rows and then another 3 rows)

I want to `Group by` first two columns(lets call them: `col1 and col2`) using having clause( `having Count(col1)>1`) and select all rows, that don't have Maximum value(per Group) in the third column.

So in this case it should be selected:

```
123123  2019-07-23 22:00:00 2019-07-04 00:00:00
123123  2019-07-23 22:00:00 2019-07-05 00:00:00
123123  2019-07-25 04:05:06 2019-07-04 00:00:00
123123  2019-07-25 04:05:06 2019-07-05 00:00:00
```

How can I do it in Oracle?

Comment: Why don't you filter directly: col3 <> TO_DATE('9999-12-31 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about that?

```
select  * from(
select col1,col2,col3,row_number() over (partition by col1,col2 order by col3 desc) rn from a
) where rn>1
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood it:

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2) as
  2    (select 123123, to_date('23.07.2019 22:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('31.12.9999 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  3     select 123123, to_date('23.07.2019 22:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('04.07.2019 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4     select 123123, to_date('23.07.2019 22:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('05.07.2019 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 123123, to_date('25.07.2019 04:05', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('31.12.9999 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  7     select 123123, to_date('25.07.2019 04:05', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('04.07.2019 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  8     select 123123, to_date('25.07.2019 04:05', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('05.07.2019 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  9    )
 10  select id, col1, col2
 11  from (select id, col1, col2,
 12               row_number() over (partition by id, col1 order by id, col1 desc, col2 desc) rn
 13        from test
 14       )
 15  where rn > 1
 16  order by id, col1, col2;

        ID COL1             COL2
---------- ---------------- ----------------
    123123 2019-07-23 22:00 2019-07-04 00:00
    123123 2019-07-23 22:00 2019-07-05 00:00
    123123 2019-07-25 04:05 2019-07-04 00:00
    123123 2019-07-25 04:05 2019-07-05 00:00
```

or (worse, as it fetches from the same table twice)

```
 <snip>
 10  select * from test t
 11  where (t.id, t.col1, t.col2) not in
 12        (select t1.id, max(t1.col1), max(t1.col2)
 13         from test t1
 14         where t1.id = t.id
 15         group by t1.id, t1.col1
 16        )
 17  order by t.id, t.col1, t.col2;

        ID COL1             COL2
---------- ---------------- ----------------
    123123 2019-07-23 22:00 2019-07-04 00:00
    123123 2019-07-23 22:00 2019-07-05 00:00
    123123 2019-07-25 04:05 2019-07-04 00:00
    123123 2019-07-25 04:05 2019-07-05 00:00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the other answers are correct, because they do not explicitly check for the maximum date.

You can get your desired results most simply with:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col3 <> '9999-12-31 00:00:00';
```

I need to assume that you really want to require that the maximum date is present (because you mention this particular value in the query) *and* then you want the other rows.  For this, I think `exists` might be appropriate:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col3 <> '9999-12-31 00:00:00' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.col1 = t.col1 and
                    t2.col2 = t.col2 and
                    t2.col3 = '9999-12-31 00:00:00'
             );
```

You can also phrase this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(col3) over (partition by col1, col2) as max_col3
      from t
     ) t
where max_col3 = '9999-12-31 00:00:00' and
     col3 <> '9999-12-31 00:00:00';
```